# Identifying motor

Tags: motor

What kind of motor is this and what is the signal used to rotate it? It has 4 coils and each coil has a pin coming out of it except for one coil (number 4) it's only connected to the coils next to it. I can measure 70 ohm resistance between (1 and 2) and (1 and 3) and the resistance between (2 and 3) is 150 ohm. I took it from a PC fan and I would like to power it with 12V adapter

[image]

Comment: Please upload your image using the image upload button on the editor toolbar. That way the question doesn't rely on links which may die as yours has already due to exceeding the bandwidth limit of your linked site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the stator for a sensorless, brushless 2-phase motor.  The fan rotor should have a ring magnet inside of it that completes the motor.  It is probably wired in a "sorta Y" configuration.

I would expect that:

- coils 1 & 3 are in series,
- coils 2 & 4 are in series,
- one end of those two series pairs is connected together, and to a pin
- the other end of coils 1 & 3 is connected to the pin on coil 1
- the other end of coils 2 & 4 is connected to the remaining pin.

These are designed to be the ultimate in cheap manufacture, and to run a fan.  They won't generate much starting torque (or much torque at all, for that matter), and they won't be easy to drive in any way that's not suitable for a fan.

I would suggest googling on "PC fan replacement motor drive" and hope that you're not inundated with articles on how to put a fan in your computer.